# How to call POST api with content type x-www-urlencoded using camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have tried by writting the processor as follows

```
    package com.example.demo;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Message;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class TokenProcessor implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        exchange.
        System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody());
        Message out = exchange.getOut();
            
        Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        map.put(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD,"POST" );
        map.put(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
    
        TokenInput tokeninput=exchange.getIn().getBody(TokenInput.class);
        System.out.println("Tokeninput="+tokeninput);
//      map.put("client_id",tokeninput.getClient_id());
//      map.put("scope",tokeninput.getScope());
//      map.put("code",tokeninput.getCode());
//      map.put("redirect_uri",tokeninput.getRedirect_uri());
//      map.put("grant_type",tokeninput.getGrant_type());
//      map.put("client_secret",tokeninput.getClient_secret());
        ObjectMapper obj=new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonStr=obj.writeValueAsString(tokeninput);
        //InputStream convertValue = obj.convertValue(tokeninput, Byte.class);
        out.setHeaders(map);
        //String encode = URLEncoder.encode(tokeninput.toString(),"utf-8");
        out.setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody());
    }
}
```

Gettring error

> org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter
> available to convert from type: com.example.demo.TokenInput to the
> required type: java.io.InputStream with value
> com.example.demo.TokenInput@ea2c54c   at
> org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:181)
> ~[camel-core-2.12.0.jar:2.12.0]   at
> org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:99)
> ~[camel-core-2.12.0.jar:2.12.0]   at
> org.apache.camel.processor.ConvertBodyProcessor.process(ConvertBodyProcessor.java:78)
> ~[camel-core-2.12.0.jar:2.12.0]

Comment: Please help me on this. I am strugling from 2 days.

Comment: If you're just trying to POST some JSON content to an endpoint, shouldn't you be setting the message body as `out.setBody(jsonStr);`?

Comment: I also have checked with out.setBody(jsonStr);

Comment: you are trying to persist a java object which isn't going to work! Can you add your camel route?

Answer (score 0):

I use it extensively in camel applications as follows.

```
    .removeHeaders("*")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
            .setBody(simple("grant_type=refresh&client_id=1233232&client_secret=mysecret"))
            .to("http://google.com");
```